# Jwplayer simple code not working in jsfiddle but working on my browser

Tags: jwplayer, jsfiddle

I am using Jwplayer for my videos to be played. 
so i was using JS fiddle to test JWplayer API

I had included JS file as instructed in jsfiddle. Video works fine but i am tring to have one button other than player control to pause/play the video  .

but it doesnt seems to work 
i am not able to understand the problem

help me out here

```
<body>


   <div id='my-video'></div><br>
    <div id="content" style=" text-align: center;">
       <button name='play' id='play' value='play' onclick='play();'>Play</button>
        <button name='pause' id='pause' value='pause' onclick='pause();' style='display: none;'>Pause</button>
    </div>


</body>


<script>
       jwplayer('my-video').setup({
        file: 'http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/lWMJeVvV-364767.mp4',
        width: '640',
        height: '360'
    });



    function play() {
        jwplayer().play();
        document.getElementById('play').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('pause').style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
    function pause() {
        jwplayer().pause();
        document.getElementById('pause').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('play').style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
</script>
```

Thank you

```
 Here is the  [DEMO LINK][1]`http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/f6ufe/17/`
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks

I am truly new to jsfiddle

I am not sure why but the function in JS portion are not working

***so I put those in html page using script tag and now it is working***

```
 can some one tell why is that so ....i have included my link which is  not working link 

 http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/f6ufe/17/

 this is my link for new code which is working
** http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/f6ufe/30/**
```

thanks for  help ..:)

Answer (score 0):

I just went to both jsfille links and they both work fine for me?

Comment: Hi Ethan ,
you r right 
code is working http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/f6ufe/17/...here as well...
but what i meant was that ... the play button which i have created in this link is not working 
http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/f6ufe/17/

whereas in this link http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/f6ufe/30/ it is working.... 

reason probably is binding is not happening properly with function 

just check it :) 

thanks for reply

Comment: I see a custom message in the upper right hand corner on both links that says "Result", which does nothing if I click it. Both links look the same otherwise no custom play button on either.

Comment: Ah, I had to scroll down. I get this error in Firebug when I click the Play button on the 1st link - TypeError: play is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

play();

I would make sure that the code is the same for both of them.